# Inverse of continuous function defined on an interval must be continuous?

Tags: calculus

I saw this theorem in a book:
"A continuous function on an interval is invertible if and only if it is strictly monotone. Moreover, the inverse is also continuous and strictly monotone."

It seems to suggest that the inverse of a continuous function must be continuous. However, it is easy to find counter example of functions that are not bicontinuous. For example, $f: [0,1) \cup [2,3] \rightarrow [0,2]$ by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x \in [0,1) \\ x-1 & x \in [2,3] \end{cases}$$
But the above function is not defined on an interval.

So is it true that for invertible continuous functions defined ON AN INTERVAL, the inverse must also be continuous?

Comment: Yes, the fact that the domain of definition is connected is essential for this to be true.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But is it true that if we only required that the function (defined on a connected domain) be continuous at a point $x_0$, then the inverse is continuous at $y_0=f(x_0)$?

Comment: continuous and bijective (or, which is the same in this case, monotonic).

Comment: Continuous and bijective in the interval --> inverse continuous in the interval. My question is if only require that the function be continuous at $x_0$ (but may not be continuous at every point in the interval, yet still invertible), must the inverse function be continuous at $y_0=f(x_0)$?

Comment: I see. I'm not sure, but would expect that you need continuity in a neighbourhood of that point to draw the conclusion.